# Расширение функционала существующих страниц админки WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Как расширить в админке редактирование "Рубрик"? Мне необходимо добавить дополнительное поле помимо существующих:
Название
Описание
Ярлык.
Это простое текстовое поле. Не картинка, не иконка. Просто текст. Как добавить в бд?
И как его значение потом в теме вытащить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По аналогии с кастом филдами для постов с версии 4.4 добавили кастомные поля для таксономий. Для вашей цели прекрасно подойдут функции [add_term_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_term_meta), [update_term_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_term_meta) и [get_term_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)